# How to build the tree with the "most different" solutions of a clustering?

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, clustering

***Illustrate the question with an example*** : we have a similarity matrix for 1000 people, and the similarity represents how much their *hobbies* are the same (it does not really matter how it's built).

Let's say that among these people :

- 50% are 15 years old and 50% are 60 years old ;
- At the same time, 33% are American, 33% are European, and 34% are Asian.

Now if we run a ***clustering algorithm*** on this dataset.

- with k = 2, groups are divided based on their age (younger / older);
- with k = 3, groups are divided based on their place of origin (US, Europe, Asia), and the cluster allocation is very different from k = 2 : many *couples* together in k = 2 are separate with k = 3 and vice versa.
- and with k = 6, groups are divided on both age and region (young US, young EU, ...)

I find it interesting to realize that :

- clusters with k = 2 and k = 3 are the most different
- cluster with k = 6 merge both

**My question is the following :**

On a more complex dataset, how to detect automatically this "*tree-like shape*" of the "*most different clustering paths*" ? In the current example it would be to detect that k = 2 and k = 3 are the two most different yet interesting clusterings; and that k = 6 is a parent of both.

I am having trouble doing bibliography on this, I tried keywords like "trees", "consensus", "most different" clustering, but I didn't find an answer.

Honestly I can't believe I am the first one to ask this question, I guess I just don't know how to formulate it correctly.

Edit : Maybe "alternative clustering" is the keyword I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) algorithms? You can choose among several distance metrics and use a [dendrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) to visualize the various splits. Standard packages like [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering) & [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html) have a number of common hierarchical clustering algorithms/visualization tools.

Comment: Yes, but actually I think it does not fit my need : in this case, it build the tree on one of two options (so age or country first) but then it won't split, so I won't see the two alternative yet correct clusterings (age / origin)